# Move Laravel Project in Production Stage

Tags: php, laravel, centos

I converted my project to a Laravel Project. And i created a new website. And it is working fine.

My real application is on .com domain. My Laravel project is on .net domain Two applications are in same server. (Server is centos)

i created and old directory and i moved my httpdocs folder on .com domain to old directory.

```
mv example.com/httpdocs example.com/old/httpdocs
```

and i moved my laravel project from .net domain to .com domain

```
mv example.net/httpdocs example.com/httpdocs
```

And i get in .com domain i'm recieving an error.

"No input file specified"

What should i do ?

Comment: Is your configuration file pointing to the public folder ?

Comment: this laravel project works in .net domain correctly. after moving to .com it fails. And do you mean htaccess file saying configuring file ?

Comment: Don't you have a server configuration file like a virtual host file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've pointed your web server to a `public` directory of your Laravel app. If you're using Apache, you should use something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.localhost.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public"
  <Directory "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart your web server.

Also, make sure all subdirectories and files were moved to a new directory.

Comment: i'm using nginx. I'll try and notify you. Thank you. I think it works.

Comment: @Cihan, Did it work for you? If it did please upvote and choose my answer as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you own both domains and planning on keeping them, you can just add a cname record to point to the .net domain.

That way both domains will point to the same instance.

Or you can do the change on your /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf and do a sudo service nginx restart